# In Outlook VBA, how can I change the subject so it changes the subject in the Explorer Pane?

Tags: vba, outlook

When I receive an email, I'm manipulating the subject line so it is more readable and "conversations" generated by a certain auto-emailer actually contain all of the thread.

I'm able to change the subject in the email view pane, but the subject remains the same in the explorer pane.  How can I force the subject to change in the Explorer Pane?  Do I have to copy the email and delete the old one?  If so, I know that the email date will change.  How can I change the email date back to the original date prior to the move?  I'm using Outlook 2007.

Comment: @Ross Rogers: does the answer below answer your question?

Comment: Probably, I just haven't had the time to install and work with OutLook Redemption.  Once I do, I'll post code and accept your answer.

Comment: Okay, great. I've used Outlook  Redemption before and it's very helpful, you'll find that it adds a lot of great functionality.

Comment: @Ross Rogers: Have you had an opportunity to look at Outlook Redemption yet?

Comment: Hi Otaku,
I haven't tried it out yet.  The problem I'm solving is just a little client-side Outlook script I use to re-write some awful corporate internal email format. My real tasks take higher priority, so I haven't had time to start working with Outlook Redemption.

Comment: @Ross Rogers: does the answer below answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late, but 2 things:  Conversation Topic...

1. ***can't*** be changed in Outlook's Object Model (VBA/VSTO)
2. ***can*** be changed by using [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/).

[This forum thread](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.office.developer.outlook.vba/topic36949.aspx) has some sample code and instructions at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you've already written the code which gets you a reference to a `MailItem` object.

You can set the `MailItem`'s Subject property to what ever you like and then call it's `Save()` method.  This should achieve what you desire regarding the mail's subject.

However, doing this also updates the mail's `ReceivedTime` property.  This is a read only property so you can't set it back to the previous timestamp. Unfortunately, there may be no way to do so.

Comment: I've set the MailItem's Subject property and called Save(), but it doesn't change the subject name in the mail browser/explorer pane ( the one that lists all the mail).

Comment: FYI, this turns out to be the "Conversation" of an email.  Still trying to find out if I can change the "Conversation" of a `mail_item`.  `ClearConversationIndex()` doesn't work for me.